# Calendly WordPress Iframe - make the email address read only

Tags: wordpress, calendly

I have a problem. My Calendly is integrated to my CRM and when users book a Calendly appt on my WordPress website I pre-populate their email address using their WP User email. However, if my clients change this email it causes all sorts of problems in my CRM and automations.

Is there a way to make the email address on the calendly iframe read only? Or even hide it? Or any other way you would approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-populate the user's unique CRM ID in the Calendly url by using one of the following query parameters:

- utm_source
- utm_campaign
- utm_medium
- utm_content
- utm_term
- sfid

example:

https://calendly.com/acmesales?sfid=UNIQUE_CRM_ID

When the Calendly event is scheduled the [webhook payload](https://calendly.stoplight.io/docs/api-docs/reference/common/models/webhookpayload.yaml) for that event will include the unique id included in the query parameters.

[image]